# "Contemporaneously" vs "concurrently" - difference in legal verbiage?

Tags: contract-law

What's the difference in meaning between "contemporaneously" and "concurrently" in contract verbiage in general?  An example could be "the following contracts are being executed contemporaneously" vs "the following contracts are being executed concurrently".

Comment: There is not enough context in this question to know if there might be a difference. Most legal questions are fact rich.

Comment: @ohwilleke I was actually interested in the difference in meaning in those two words in general.  I'll revise my question to better reflect.

Comment: @g491 if you are looking for English meanings rather than legal ones, English se is a better fit.

Comment: @g491 If you are looking for different legal meanings of two words in general you are likely to lead yourself astray. The assumption that words have a general legal meaning that applies in the same way in different contexts is frequently incorrect. It is unsound to assume that because you know what a word means in one sentence of even the same document that it will mean the same thing in a different sentence of that document (e.g. the  word "significantly" has two different meanings when used in different sentences in Treas. Reg. 1.83-1 that was the subject to a recent question in this forum).

Answer (score 1):

Absent some explicit definition to the contrary, words in contracts assume their conventional connotations.

Absent any particular context, *contemporaneous* is synonymous with *concurrent*.  However, one *could* argue that the latter connotes more strict simultaneity.

A good contract would specify its terms to avoid any such ambiguity.